# Could not add the parameter --listen to open tcp socket

Tags: libvirt

I was installed libvirtd successfully in Ubuntu20, but when add the parameter -l or --listen to enable tcp socket, service will restart failed.
The file /etc/default/libvirtd shown like below:

```
# Defaults for libvirtd initscript (/etc/init.d/libvirtd)
# This is a POSIX shell fragment
# Start libvirtd to handle qemu/kvm:
start_libvirtd="yes"

# options passed to libvirtd, see man libvirtd for details.
# For example to enable listening on tcp add -l here
# and set up the TLS Certificates that libvirtd will need.
libvirtd_opts="-l " # won't work with -l or --listen or -d -l
libvirtd_opts="" # work without tcp socket 

# pass in location of kerberos keytab
#export KRB5_KTNAME=/etc/libvirt/libvirt.keytab

# Whether to mount a systemd like cgroup layout (only
# useful when not running systemd)
#mount_cgroups=yes
# Which cgroups to mount
#cgroups="memory devices"
```

Also the config file /etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf is:

```
listen_tls = 0
listen_tcp = 1
tcp_port = "16509"
listen_addr = "0.0.0.0"
auth_tcp = "none"
```

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `systemctl status libvirtd.service` it ought to tell you why it has failed. Most likely it is because Ubuntu has it configured to use socket activation, which makes use of `--listen` obsolete, instead replacing it with a `libvirtd-tcp.socket` unit file. Further info is in the man pages https://libvirt.org/manpages/libvirtd.html#system-socket-activation

Comment: Thanks and that works for me, using systemctl start libvirtd-tcp.socket to start tcp socket as a service.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file /etc/default/libvirtd.
If the start options contains something like:
libvirtd_opts='-l' or libvirtd_opts='--listen'

Remove the option and the libvirtd will start.